# Html can not name correctly

Tags: html, visual-studio, file

I have got a really strange problem with visual studio code. When i want to create a html file a vs show it like a text documentation. when i write with mistake htm vs show like a normal html file.
But my older html files is name correctly, and work normal. This is  only my new files

Comment: What does VS Code show as the document mod?:This is shown in the status bar. Eg. "XML" or "JSON" (two examples I have open here).

Comment: the status show "JSON"

Comment: That will be why. If VS Code thinks the file is JSON it will format it as JSON. Try changing the language mode to HTML.

Comment: thanks i change this (:

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file to "HTML" at the bottom right side of VS.

[image: You can change the file to HTML at the bottom right side of VS.]

Also at the first save of an new file you can type ".html" after your file name.